# Transferring a misplaced question after it has a positively received answer

Tags: discussion

I recently goof'd and forgot that hsm.stackexchange exists, and posted a history of mathematics [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451991/who-was-the-first-to-propose-a-formal-definition-of-infinity) here.

This was kindly pointed out to me by a user here, but the question already had a positively received [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/451994/92164) by the time I was notified, and the question is thusly precluded from deletion; reposting it elsewhere without deleting this one feels redundant. This leads me to ask:

> Is there a standard remedy in cases like this, to migrate a misplaced question while preserving any valuable answers it has received?

If there is no comunity-level tool to address this situation, there is obviously deus ex machina moderator migration to fall back on; if moderators are the only remedy, this post seems a good place to list putative misplaced questions and appeal to moderators for question migration.

Comment: My opinion: there's nothing wrong with having the question on both sites, so long as you link each to the other.

Comment: Should this be tagged (migration)? BTW [migration](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/migration/info) preserves the answers, too. However, only the mods can migrate to [hsm.se]. See the FAQ and various previous discussions: [What outgoing migration paths should we have?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/141) (and the [questions linked there](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/141)) or [When voting to close, only 3 alternative SE listed as options](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5315) (and the [questions linked there](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/linked/5315)).

Comment: It is worth mentioning that migration to [hsm.se] wasn't without controversy in the past. (OTOH it is a bit different if this is requested directly by the OP.)
Some previous discussions: [Is there a consensus on whether history of mathematics questions are acceptable on MO?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/394) and [Why was "The origin(s) of the word “elliptic” migrated to hsm?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4566).